# tracking the slave lag

Tags: mysql, replication

I have master-master setup and I noticed that the active master can handle several simultaneous queries at a time while the slave reads one query at a time and takes a lot of time to catch up.

1) Is there any solution to this?

2) Why does the slave shows 0 seconds as "seconds_behind_maser". There are times when it shows the correct number of seconds that it is behind. But in my case, it is showing 0 seconds while still reading from the log.

3) Why does mmm_control shows that both Masters are online while I expected one master to be in "awaiting recovery" state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the master it doesnt matter what order simultanious updates/rollbacks/timeouts etc take place. As whatever it did to resolve a conflict is right and the clients are given the correct feedback.

The slave however must execute the updates in exactly the same order as the master, the only way to acheive this is to run the updates sequentially in the order the master commited them. So not only must it single thread, it can only start work after the master has commited. Usually this means when the commit log record is flushed to disk, so there is actual physical IO to wait for.

Comment: How do I ensure high availability? Isn't replication worth an option?

Answer (score 0):

Re: 1) Although multiple statements can be executing on the active master at once, the replication execution process is single-thread to ensure data consistency between servers.

I've never used it, but you might want to investigate [Maatkit's](http://www.maatkit.org/) [mk-slave-prefetch](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-slave-prefetch.html) to warm up your slave in hopes of speeding up your updates.

Re: 2) The slave will show 0 seconds behind master if doesn't have anything to execute from the fetching thread yet. This can often happen in environments with high network latency (relative to the execution thread).